# Vertical Parallax Scrolling Of UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, parallax, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a vertical parallax scrolling effect between several views that are all the size of the screen.

This wasn't too complicated when done through buttons, however I want it to be controlled by a UIPanGesture, similar to the [Year Walk Companion App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/year-walk-companion/id597879895?mt=8) for iOS. The current equation shown here doesn't work correctly.

Currently this version only moves the first two views, because once I get those working the rest should be easy. I've also not included all the checks that would stop certain views moving in certain directions because that is also not relevant to the issue.

Here is a web version of it working with buttons: http://flycarpodacus.zxq.net/iPhone%20Parallax/event.html

Hope someone can help.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture;
    int activeView;
    int nextView;
    float offset;
    float speed;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view4;
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize view1, view2, view3, view4;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    activeView = 1;
    offset = 220;
    speed = 1;
    panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    if (self.view.frame.size.height != 568) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
        view1.frame = frame;
        view2.frame = frame;
        view3.frame = frame;
        view4.frame = frame;
    }

    view4.center = CGPointMake(view4.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2 + offset);
    view3.center = CGPointMake(view3.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2 + offset);
    view2.center = CGPointMake(view2.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2 + offset);
    view1.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
}
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint panGestureTranslation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

    switch (activeView) {
        case 1:
            view1.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, panGestureTranslation.y + self.view.frame.size.height/2);
            view2.center = CGPointMake(view2.center.x, view2.center.y - 2.5f);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, in my point of view you could try to do something like that :

first use only two view, in your example only two view is visible at the same time and so you could re-use the view for
the next slide you want to display.

So at the start you have 2 views (lets say they have the same size than the screen 300x500, yes I know they are not the real size,
but it will be more easy for the math :p). 
In you init function place you view one in position 150x250 (the center of the screen), and the screen 2 at 150x500 (so you see only 
the upper half of your view).

lets call panGestureTranslation.y : DeltaY (it will be more quick). so in the function panGestureRecognizer you want to move the two view
with the parralex effect, one simple solution in this exact case will be to move view1 of 2*DeltaY and view2 of DeltaY, like that, when the view1 
will have quit the screen completly, the view two will be right in the center of it.

"
view1.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, view1.center.y + 2*DeltaY);
view2.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, view2.center.y + DeltaY);
"

you can know if is finish by test the position of view one (if the position.y is <= than 0, so it's finish.

when is finish, you have two choice, first you put the view1 in the bottom of view2 (at position 150x500 and display behind view2 ) and you feel it with your 3rd content, then switch a booleen
to do the excact opposite the next frame (you will move view2 of 2*DeltaY and view1 of DeltaY).

other solution is to move the two view at the original position (view1 at 150x250 and view two at 150x500), and feel view1 with the content of view2 (you have to do it without animation 
so the user doesn't see that the view have switch), and feel view2 with you 3rd content, and so next frame, the exact same code will work again. you can have an infinity of content with this method.

"
view1.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, view1.center.y + 2*DeltaY);
view2.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x, view2.center.y + DeltaY);
"

let me know if I wasn't clear on some point ^^.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest checking our article on parallax effect with detailed explanation and open source implementation => http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/08/parallax-in-ios-applications/?lang=en

Comment: Answers in the form of a link are not the way to do it